# Finding the most popular element with C# given O(1) space complexity requirement

Tags: c#, algorithm, complexity

I have tried to solve the following problem in C# with LINQ:

> Given an integer array, find the most frequent number and it's count in the array. If multiple numbers have the same highest frequency return the smallest number.

One requirement here is also to make the code execute in O(1) space complexity.

```
public struct MostPoularItem
{
    public MostPoularItem(int item, int count)
    {
        Item = item;
        Count = count;
    }

    public int Item { get; }
    public int Count { get; }
}

public static class Utils
{
    public static MostPoularItem FindMostPopularElement(int[] integers)
    {
        if(integers == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(integers));
        }

        return integers.GroupBy(x => x)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
            .Select(x => new MostPoularItem(x.Key, x.Count()))
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Would be nice to have someone else's eye on this, especially around trying to see if there is any room of improving its time and space complexity. Feel free to offer alternative solutions which don't also use LINQ as well.

Comment: LINQ is compact but it is not efficient.  Why are you limiting to LINQ?

Comment: @Paparazzi I just wanted to see if that would be possible with LINQ. I will change to the question to reflect that it doesn't have to be LINQ :)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, this is *not* O(1) space complexity.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't have \$O(1)\$ space complexity at the moment, `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` (used wrong as pointed out in the other answer(s)) will have a non-constant space complexity.

Since runtime is not the problem here, we can make this a space complexity of \$O(1)\$ pretty easily:

```
Tuple<int, int> GetItemWithMaxCount(int[] items)
{
    var maxCount = 0;
    var maxItem = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        var currentCount = 1;
        var currentItem = items[i];

        foreach (var item in items.Skip(i + 1))
        {
            if (item == currentItem)
            {
                currentCount++;
            }
        }

        if (currentCount > maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = currentCount;
            maxItem = currentItem;
        }
        else if (currentCount == maxCount)
        {
            if (currentItem < maxItem)
            {
                maxItem = currentItem;
            }
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<int, int>(maxItem, maxCount);
}
```

Return an actual class if you like.

The downside of this? Time complexity is \$O(n^2)\$ (I think), but it's guaranteed to use constant space. We also cannot build a lookup of previous iterations, as that would use more than constant space.

Essentially, we just loop through all the items `n` times, then loop *from that item on*. This is a trick to help us prevent iterating the same item multiple times. We know that each index can only have a specific value in it so we can skip the that value (and all previous ones) in the inner loop.

There's no complex LINQ here, no additional arrays, no sorting. Just go through them all and add them up then compare to the current max. The `.Skip(i + 1)` method *is* part of LINQ, but you can get around that pretty easily by changing that iteration up (swap the `foreach` out):

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < items.Length; j++)
{
    if (items[j] == currentItem)
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

This can be ordered, unordered, whatever. It meets all your criteria: return item with most counts and count or lowest value item with most counts and count if a tie.

This solution is *similar* (has the same general effect) to the solution presented [in this answer by Peter Taylor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150495/73844), but the key advantage here is that we can optimize it for our requirements. We've already made one optimization: skilling the first `i` elements. Just as well, that answer will not use constant space because of `Select`, which appears to use a significant amount of space.

As an example, you can increase speed (slightly) by skipping duplicates as we *can* with our constant space requirement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    var currentCount = 1;
    var currentItem = items[i];

    if (currentItem == maxItem)
    {
        continue;
    }

    foreach (var item in items.Skip(i + 1))
```

Basically, that `if` will mean that if we are iterating a value *again* (mind you, it can change, so we can still check the same value twice, but if it's the current max we'll skip it to maintain our space complexity) we can skip it for the moment.

---

If you read about LINQ-to-objects (which is what we're using) it uses a [Stable Quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792074/what-sorting-algorithm-is-used-by-linq-orderby) to do it's sorting.

One thing we know about quicksort is that [worst-case space complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is \$O(n)\$ for a naive implementation, and \$O(log(n))\$ for an optimized implementation.

This means that *any solution presented* that uses LINQ to order the elements is going to use \$O(log(n))\$ space complexity.

And of course, I have to *prove* that this uses \$O(1)\$ space (or, at least, less space than the OP) so I ran BenchmarkDotNet against my code and OP code:

```
            Method |            Mean |      StdDev |   Gen 0 | Allocated |
------------------ |---------------- |------------ |-------- |---------- |
      OriginalCode |   1,718.1155 us |   7.6080 us |       - | 327.31 kB |
      EBrownAnswer |  28,547.8824 us |  48.4272 us |       - |     512 B |
```

Mine took 130 times as long (expected) but ran in 0.15% of the space. So, how do the other answers stack up?

Well, once we put all the answers together (the one by Peter Taylor doesn't return the correct object, but let's just try that one out as well anyway) we get the following:

```
            Method |            Mean |      StdDev |   Gen 0 | Allocated |
------------------ |---------------- |------------ |-------- |---------- |
      OriginalCode |   1,718.1155 us |   7.6080 us |       - | 327.31 kB |
      EBrownAnswer |  28,547.8824 us |  48.4272 us |       - |     512 B |
  RubberDuckAnswer |   1,183.3647 us |   3.5244 us | 20.3125 | 302.64 kB |
 PeterTaylorAnswer | 255,862.3770 us | 201.6448 us |       - | 760.33 kB |
   HeslacherAnswer |      62.5081 us |   0.3105 us |       - |   8.23 kB |
   PaparazziAnswer |     882.7228 us |   2.9597 us |       - | 157.98 kB |
```

So there we have it. Looks like the only version that *actually* had \$O(1)\$ space complexity was the version I posted here. If you can relax that requirement *slightly* then the version Heslacher posted is the most superior version to use.

If you want a *truly* optimal solution based off of both metrics of each method (we'll define best as the lowest of time * memoryInBytes), we have the following:

```
           Method |          Weighted Result |
----------------- |------------------------- |
     OriginalCode |     575,852,937.5283 usB |
     EBrownAnswer |      14,616,515.7888 usB |
 RubberDuckAnswer |     366,728,696.6354 usB |
PeterTaylorAnswer | 199,208,797,290.9158 usB |
  HeslacherAnswer |         526,728.4275 usB |
   PaparazziAnswer|     142,799,409.0947 usB |
```

The answer posted by Heslacher comes in first, again.

Do note, however, that method is not without it's flaws. As the range between integers grows bigger, the method uses more space. If we're using unbounded `int` ranges, Heslacher's answer will **not** work at all. (It will crash on negatives **and** on extremely large ranges.)

Do note: list generation is *not* measured for each of these methods and is defined as:

```
const int _integerCount = 10000;

private static int[] GetItems()
{
    var list = new int[_integerCount];
    var rand = new Random(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < _integerCount; i++)
    {
        list[i] = rand.Next(0, 2048);
    }

    return list;
}
```

So, if we adjust our integer range to fall within `0` and `short.MaxValue` (`32767`), we get the following results:

```
          Method |           Mean |     StdDev |   Gen 0 |   Gen 1 |   Gen 2 | Allocated |     Result Weighted |
---------------- |--------------- |----------- |-------- |-------- |-------- |---------- |-------------------- |
    EBrownAnswer | 28,408.5030 us | 34.7946 us |       - |       - |       - |     512 B | 14,545,153.5360 usB |
 HeslacherAnswer |    119.7295 us |  0.4404 us | 36.8164 | 36.8164 | 36.8164 | 131.42 kB | 16,112,487.3114 usB |
```

As this shows, our fastest answer is not *always* the best. For large ranges of integers (or anything above ~500m, or any values below 0) that solution will fail, sadly. :(

And believe it or not, for small, highly-variable data-sets this algorithm is the fastest (number count = `100`, vary from 0 to `short.MaxValue`):

```
            Method |       Mean |    StdDev | Scaled | Scaled-StdDev |   Gen 0 |   Gen 1 |   Gen 2 | Allocated |
------------------ |----------- |---------- |------- |-------------- |-------- |-------- |-------- |---------- |
      OriginalCode | 39.0327 us | 0.1790 us |   1.00 |          0.00 |  0.5615 |       - |       - |   9.91 kB |
      EBrownAnswer |  4.6140 us | 0.3984 us |   0.12 |          0.01 |       - |       - |       - |      16 B |
  RubberDuckAnswer | 25.2577 us | 0.0717 us |   0.65 |          0.00 |  0.3499 |       - |       - |   8.39 kB |
 PeterTaylorAnswer | 34.0133 us | 0.1991 us |   0.87 |          0.01 |  0.0651 |       - |       - |   7.76 kB |
   HeslacherAnswer | 30.2370 us | 0.0269 us |   0.77 |          0.00 | 40.3239 | 40.3239 | 40.3239 | 131.42 kB |
   PaparazziAnswer | 17.5162 us | 0.0507 us |   0.45 |          0.00 |  0.5412 |       - |       - |   6.09 kB |
```

Comment: And note that GroupBy cannot possibly use any less than O(n) space, so the OP's implementation will never be any better than that.

Comment: How do you get 8.23 kB for Heslacher?   An Int32 is 4 bytes.

Comment: @Paparazzi Because the range of integers was 0 to 2048, 2048 * 4 ~8192 (8.23kB). If the range is from `int.MinValue` to `int.MaxValue`, Heslacher's solution will throw an exception.

Comment: If you optimise quicksort for space rather than for constant factor in the time then you can get it to run in constant space and O(n lg n) time. I'm not sure that anyone has ever written an implementation that does that, but it's doable. Also note that (as pointed out by Servy in a different comment thread) "Allocated" doesn't tell you the space complexity. `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) var b = new int[1];`has O(1) space complexity, but unless the compiler optimises heavily it allocates O(N) space.

Comment: Nice answer and nice analysis.  I was surprised by the results so I tested on my environment.   I ran mine and your 100 times each and I am getting 350 milliseconds for mine and 165,000 milliseconds for yours.    They are both returning the same result.    Naturally if you take the array from 10,000 to 100,000 the difference gets bigger.

Comment: @Paparazzi Of course, like I said, my method is O(1) space complexity but it is an O(n^2) time complexity. This means that if you increase array size by 10x, the time *should* (and my benchmark showed that it did) go up by 100x.

Comment: @EBrown Cool - you don't need to reply.  Even with 10,000 I am seeing  huge differences.  Can you share how you tested?

Comment: @Paparazzi BenchmarkDotNet - I dropped all the code for everyone's answer in a class, added a `NameAnswer()` method that called `PersonCodeMethod()` with the `[Benchmark]` attribute and fed the list (a `private readonly` field populated with `GetItems()` to it. BenchmarkDotNet is taking the average of the execution times on my machine for the report. Every algorithm was fed the exact same list.

Comment: @Paparazzi Also, I've *noticed* that depending on the implementation, the execution time (between yours, mine and Heslacher's) all very based on different criteria. If the range of values is larger, all of them take more time (bad thing about early returns, etc.) but for some reason the version you posted is taking *significantly* more time. If I use values of `0` or `1` in `1k` integer spaces, yours takes less time than mine, but if I use values of `0` to `short.MaxValue`, mine becomes the fastest.

Comment: @Paparazzi If you want to talk more about it feel free to drop in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and we can discuss more.

Comment: @EBrown I was late to answer this question, but maybe you could look at my heapsort version.  Mine modifies the input array though, so I don't know if that means you have to benchmark it last or separately.

Comment: @JS1 I will definitely benchmark it when I get some time after I sleep. :)

Comment: @PeterTaylor: `quicksort […] in constant space` - can you please give a reference? How, worst case, do you avoid _Ω(log n)_ call frames/stack entries to keep track of work to do _without "tweaking items"_? - I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463003/3789665), _tripling_ (?) the number of key comparisons.

Comment: @greybeard, I don't have a reference for the whole thing, but the key is [quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). It allows you to force the partitions of quicksort so that the "recursion" is so structured that you can make the stack of start and end indices implicit: after sorting a range \$[s, s + 2^k)\$ you move on to either \$[s + 2^k, s + 2^k + 2^k)\$ or \$[s + 2^k, s + 2^k + 2^{k+1})\$ according to value of \$s\bmod{2^k}\$ - details left as exercise ;). Using the worse-case-linear variant of quickselect, you get a worst-case quasilinear quicksort.

Comment: With the mutually recursive [median-of-medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Algorithm) implementation from en.wikipedia, the analysis promises to get, err, interesting. Probably, there is a constant space variant of Floyd-Rivest…

Answer (score 9):

> ```
>     return integers.GroupBy(x => x)
>         .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
>         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
>         .Select(x => new MostPoularItem(x.Key, x.Count()))
>         .FirstOrDefault();
> ```

Calling `OrderByDescending` after `OrderBy` will destroy the previous sorting.

If you want to apply another sorting I think you mean to do it for a group and not the entire collection. In this case you should use `ThenByDescending`.

```
return integers
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Count())
    .Select(x => new MostPoularItem(x.Key, x.Count()))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

**Disclaimer**: My review is not about the space complexity but pointing out the `OrderBy`-bug.

---

See the amazing [review by @EBrown's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150522/59161) for detailed information and benchmarks.

Answer (score 8):

Your solution appears to be correct, although I can't speak to the space complexity of it. Linq makes complex things look easy. There's a lot going on "behind the scenes" here.

Anyway, let's look at the heart of your code here.

```
    return integers.GroupBy(x => x)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
        .Select(x => new MostPoularItem(x.Key, x.Count()))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

My biggest (only?) complaint about this code is that you've made it harder to understand than it needs to be by reusing the `x` identifier for a number of different things. Here's an alternative that I think makes it a bit easier to read.

```
    return integers.GroupBy(n => n)
        .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
        .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())
        .Select(group => new MostPoularItem(group.Key, group.Count()))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This makes it more clear that after the `GroupBy` call, we're no longer working with an `IEnumerable<int>`, but with an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,int>>`. I've found that people are a bit too quick to overly shorten variable names in lambda expressions. Having a short scope doesn't excuse us from naming variables well.

Comment: "Having a short scope doesn't excuse us from naming variables well."  I think the salient point was that in a single expression it's being used for different things (though even then, I still think it's pretty clear by context).  Certainly if you start introducing nested `y` and `z` things are quickly getting out of control.  But if you're interacting with one type only, I think a single letter variable is as valid as using `i` in a `for` loop when there's no nesting. (though obviously subjective)

Comment: It can be valid @KirkWoll, yes. You're also right that reusing the identifier was the main problem, but I've noticed this trend toward single letter variable names as if the fact that it's a lambda expression prevents us from using more descriptive identifiers... It's just an observation I've made.

Comment: I concur with your observation, and when my code is reviewed I've had to fix some of that up in my own code! ;)

Comment: @KirkWoll *cough* I might get called out on it a fair bit at work myself...

Comment: Calling `OrderByDescending` after `OrderBy` will distroy the previous sorting, I think you meant to use `ThenByDescending` to sort within key scope by `Count` also enumerating the group twice with the `Count()` can hurt performance. If you need to use it twice then projecting it into a new type with `Select` might be faster.

Comment: @t3chb0t those are good points worthy of their own answer. Nice catch.

Comment: @t3chb0t that's an amazing catch, thx!

Comment: LINQ `OrderBy` (and related methods) are **not** O(1) space complexity, FWIW.

Answer (score 8):

> One requirement here is also to make the code execute in O(1) space complexity.

That's going to preclude an elegant solution (with or without Linq). In particular, `GroupBy` uses O(n) space, so that's out. (So's `OrderBy`). Technically you could say

```
integers.Select(i => new MostPopularItem(i, integers.Where(j => i == j).Count()))
        .Max(mpi => mpi.Count)
```

but that's hideous.

The nicest solution I can see with that space complexity is to quick-sort in place (assuming that's permitted) and then do a linear scan to count each distinct value. But that's not Linq, and I wouldn't be surprised to learn that modifying the input is banned. (Although in that case why is it an `int[]` instead of an `IReadOnlyList<int>`?)

Comment: This code returns the *largest count* of the items, but not the `MostPopularItem` for that largest count.

Comment: And I just learned that this doesn't use O(1) space either, looks like `Select` creates a new list instance before `Max` is called.

Comment: @EBrown Select is O(1) space.  It allocates an iterator object, but it's just one object; it doesn't scale in memory with the size of the sequence, so it's O(1).

Comment: @Servy Curiously when I benchmarked this version it used 2x the memory of OP's version though. Explanation?

Comment: @EBrown How large was your data set?  For a very small data set, a fairly small fixed size value may well be more than another algorithm who's space is dependant on the size of the collection.  If you had a collection of size 100 billion, you'd get different results.

Comment: I used 10k elements ranging from 0 to 2048.

Comment: @EBrown That's not a very large data set at all; noise of the system could easily drown that out.  Nothing here is going to be any more than constant memory.

Comment: @Servy Right, but it was using 700kB for that data set, the OP solution used 350kB, look at the benchmark results in my answer, they should help explain. It's *definitely* using a lot more memory than the sorting solutions even.

Comment: @EBrown That would make it a problem with your testing approach then.  For starters, total memory used tells you nothing about the big O of the space complexity.  To see that you need to graph it as the size of the list increases.  But anyway, like I said, nothing in this code is going to hold any non-constant amount of memory, so clearly *something* is wrong in how you're testing it.  LIke I said, the very small data set is likely at least one problem.

Comment: @Servy I'm using BenchmarkDotNet which everyone *always* recommends and says "this is the best thing ever" and it's giving me that result, perhaps you should test it and demonstrate to me how to show that this method **is** using constant memory.

Comment: @EBrown So I see what you did wrong.  You're looking at the total amount of memory allocated.  This approach allocates lots of memory, but it's all extremely short lived.  There is never more than a constant amount of memory that's rooted at any one time, but lots of memory is created and immediately aging, which you counted in your test.

Comment: @EBrown, that's funny, I was looking at referencesource for Enumerable and I somehow read the signature as returning `TSource`. Must be a case of seeing what made sense (and, let's face it, finding the maximum `int` could be done with a `Select`, so the overload which takes a function is pointless syntactic sugar) rather than what was actually implemented.

Answer (score 7):

**Validation**

> ```
> if(integers == null) 
> {
>     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(integers));
> }
> ```

well, this is a start but do you think that an array containing no elements should be seen as valid ? IMO no. So another validation needs to take place like so

```
if (integers.Length == 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Passed in array doesn't contain any items");

}
```

---

To speed this up for the edge case that the array only contains one item I would add

```
if (integers.Length == 1)
{
    return new MostPoularItem(integers[0], 1);
}
```

---

That being said, I would like to show a way using arrays where the complexity surely won't fit your needs but it is pretty fast.

I will use a second array which is as big as the biggest number in `integers` to count the number of occurances like so

```
public static MostPoularItem FindMostPopularElement(int[] integers)
{
    if (integers == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("integers");
    }
    if (integers.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Passed in array doesn't contain any items");

    }
    if (integers.Length == 1)
    {
        return new MostPoularItem(integers[0], 1);
    }


    int[] counts = new int[integers.Max() + 1];

    int maxCount = -1;
    int maxItem = int.MaxValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < integers.Length; i++)
    {
        int value = integers[i];
        counts[value] += 1;

        if (counts[value] > maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = counts[value];
            maxItem = value;
        }
        else if (counts[value] == maxCount && maxItem > value)
        {
            maxItem = value;
        }
    }

    return new MostPoularItem(maxItem, maxCount);

}
```

Using poor man benchmarking (using stopwatch including warm up) and filled the `integers` like so

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] values = new int[10000001];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    values[i] = rand.Next(1000000);
}
```

the timings are for 10 runs

@t3chb0t :  77598 ms
@Paparazzi: 19254 ms
mine:       1198 ms

Comment: Thanks! Did you mean to have `int[] counts = new int[integers.Length + 1];` instead of `int[] counts = new int[integers.Max() + 1];`?

Comment: No, because I use the values of the `integers` as index.

Comment: @Heslacher The problem with this answer is that negative numbers, and numbers greater than ~500million will break it.

Answer (score 5):

#### Can be done in \$O(n \log n)\$ time and \$O(1)\$ space

I'm a little late to this question, but so far no one has come up with a better solution than \$O(n^2)\$ time and \$O(1)\$ space.

If you simply use a heapsort, which uses \$O(1)\$ space, you can achieve \$O(n \log n)\$ time as well.  Heapsort is an in-place sort, but unlike quicksort it is not recursive, so it doesn't use \$O(\log n)\$ space.  Also, it is quite simple - my version is only about 25 lines or so.  I ran it with a 10 million element array and it finished in 2.56 seconds.  Maybe someone can benchmark it versus the other solutions.

#### Sample heapsort solution

```
using System;

class sort
{
    static void Heap_PushDown(int [] heap, int heapSize, int parent)
    {
        int child = parent + parent + 1;

        while (child < heapSize) {
            if (child + 1 < heapSize && heap[child + 1] > heap[child])
                child = child + 1;
            if (heap[parent] >= heap[child])
                break;

            int tmp      = heap[parent];
            heap[parent] = heap[child];
            heap[child]  = tmp;
            parent       = child;
            child        = parent + parent + 1;
        }
    }

    static Tuple<int, int> GetItemWithMaxCount(int[] items)
    {
        int heapSize = items.Length;

        // Build the initial heap.
        for (int i = heapSize / 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            Heap_PushDown(items, heapSize, i);
        }

        // Do the heap sort.
        while (heapSize > 0) {
            int tmp         = items[0];
            items[0]        = items[--heapSize];
            items[heapSize] = tmp;
            Heap_PushDown(items, heapSize, 0);
        }

        // Find the most common item in the sorted array.
        int currentCount = 1;
        int maxItem      = items[0];
        int maxCount     = currentCount;
        for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++) {
            if (items[i] == items[i-1]) {
                currentCount++;
                if (currentCount > maxCount) {
                    maxItem  = items[i-1];
                    maxCount = currentCount;
                }
            } else {
                currentCount = 1;
            }
        }

        return new Tuple<int, int>(maxItem, maxCount);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int size = 10000000;
        int[] values = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            values[i] = rand.Next(size);
        }
        Tuple<int, int> t = GetItemWithMaxCount(values);
        System.Console.WriteLine(t.Item1);
        System.Console.WriteLine(t.Item2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quicksort can be made to run in O(n lg n) time and O(1) space using an exact median subalgorithm, but it's true that the constant factor would probably be quite a bit more than the heapsort.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Practically speaking, even a regular quicksort would only need a fixed stack of say, 64 elements because that would allow you to sort \$2^{64}\$ elements, which is an amount larger than the number of atoms in the universe.  This assumes you always push the larger partition on the stack first.  To achieve true \$O(1)\$ space yes you would need to do what you said and find the exact median so you could deduce the previous range from the smaller range.

Comment: Actually since the input is an array it can't have more than \$2^{32}\$ elements. Very good point.

Answer (score 2):

OP relaxed the LINQ constraint
This is fresh code as existing code is all LINQ
Pretty sure this in O(n) in time and O(n) in space
It fails on the O(1) space but it will be the best time (I think)
Many of the posted LINQ solutions I think are not O(1) space

```
public static MostPoularItem FindMostPopularElement(int[] integers)
{
    if (integers.Count() == 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    //Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>(integers.Count()/2);
    //for space start with 0 - for speed integers.Count()/2
    Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach(int i in integers)
    {
        if(dic.Keys.Contains(i))
            dic[i]++;
        else
            dic.Add(i, 1);
    }
    KeyValuePair<int, int> mpi = dic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                                    .ThenBy(x => x.Key)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
    return new MostPoularItem(mpi.Key, mpi.Value);
}
```

this is a faster version of EWbrown but on my machine mine is still faster at an array size of 10,000 and the O(n*n) just dies at 100,000

```
public static MostPoularItem GetItemWithMaxCountB(int[] items)
{
    int maxCount = 0;
    int maxItem = 0;
    int currentItem;
    int itemsLength = items.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsLength - 1; i++)
    {
        if (maxCount > itemsLength - i)
            break;
        currentItem = items[i];
        if (currentItem == maxItem)
            continue;
        var currentCount = 1;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < items.Length; j++)
        {
            if (items[j] == currentItem)
            {
                currentCount++;
            }
            else if (maxCount > currentCount + itemsLength - i)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (currentCount > maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = currentCount;
            maxItem = currentItem;
        }
        else if (currentCount == maxCount & currentItem < maxItem)
        {
            maxItem = currentItem;
        }
    }
    return new MostPoularItem(maxItem, maxCount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! there are a few things that I would like to touch on. first: you are creating a dictionary and doing the book keeping inside it. That dictionary size will differ depending on the size of the input. So, it must be O(N) space, no? second thing: you create the dictionary by setting it's capacity to half of the input's size. How are you sure that it will not exceed that capacity as there are no assurance that input will only have unique values.

Comment: @tugberk If Dictionary exceeds that then it will grow.   I was wrong this will NOT be O(1) space.

Comment: Nice solution, it's also how I'd do it in Python.